# How to supress data from php curl init?

Tags: php

I am using this code to test making a connection with curl:

```
$url = "https://www.google.com";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_errno($ch)==0 or die("Protocol SSLv3 Disabled.\n\nError:".curl_errno($ch)." ".curl_error($ch));
    fseek($fp, 0);//rewind
    $str='';
    while(strlen($str.=fread($fp,8192))==8192);
    echo $str;
```

The output looks like this:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 74.125.237.211...
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.237.211) port 443 (#0)
* SSL connection using SSLv3 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=www.google.com
*    start date: 2015-04-08 14:16:31 GMT
*    expire date: 2015-07-07 00:00:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*    SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Location: https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=0FY_Vd7PD8yN8Qe80IEI
< Content-Length: 261
< Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 09:45:52 GMT
< Server: GFE/2.0
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
```

I would like to suppress all the information shown after the SSL information. Basically everything from `> HEAD / HTTP 1.1` and down I don't want to be displayed.

Any ideas on how to can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have the verbose parameter set to 1. Perhaps you can set it to 0 and show the output.

i was looking for how to get the output verbose :)

Comment: if i set it to 0 then no results are displayed

Comment: but dont you need to do something with the result, curl doesnt print the result as output. 

var_dump($result); willl dump all the result (warning this may be html) so you may want to do a html_entities on it